# How to use RestSharp for Google Authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I have built a windows phone 7 app with a "sign in with google" function. Google library is not compatible with windows phone runtime so I choose RestSharp.

The app has successfully received a authentication code from Google, and the next step is to exchange the code for an access token and a refresh token. Here I encountered some problem.

```
var request = new RestRequest(this.TokenEndPoint, Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("code", code);
request.AddParameter("client_id", this.ClientId);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", this.Secret);
request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
client.ExecuteAsync<???>(request, (response) =>
            {
                var passIn = response;
            }); // how to use this method?
```

I'm not sure how to use the `client.ExecuteAsync<T>` method (or any other would be helpful) to get the response from Google. Is there any other code pre-requested for me to use such method? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind a UI element to display the response. That seems to be the gist of the problem you've outlined.

If you want to display the response in your application, you should have a UI element bound to an internal data structure.

Displaying the response

// in xaml, for example MainPage.xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="myResponseTextBox">
```

// in the corresponding MainPage.xaml.cs

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
{

   myResponseTextBox.text = response.Content; 

});
```

The Text box will display the result of the callback *when* it completes.

Comment: my problem is like the callback won't be invoked if some other codes are being executed. This is a good solution to it, thanks!

Comment: Also, the code inside the action should be wrapped in a dispatcher so it gets executed on the UI thread

    `client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
    {
       Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
       {
          myResponseTextBox.text = response.Content; 
       });
    });`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
{
    var dataToBeParsed = response.Content;
});
```

Comment: Hi Maka, the fact is i need to retrieve info from `dataToBeParsed` and display it in my app page. Here I'm not sure if 1) the `dataToBeParsed` has been received 2) since it is executed async, how can i make my program to wait till this line of code has been executed? If i put a break point at `var dataToBeParsed = response.Content;`, the program will return error before this point is reached since the next line of code in the calling function is executed unexpected.